# How can I set <img> margins that only apply within a specific class?

Tags: css, image, html, margin

In the head section of my page I have the html:

```
img {
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-right:15px;
}
```

I set these rules to affect rollover images within a certain CSS class, but I would like the rest of the images on the page to be unaffected. Is there a way to specify those rules within the class? Like a sort of img variant rule?

The class I am trying to affect looks like this in my attached style sheet:

```
.menu {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: If they are inside menu than you can use `.menu img {}`

Comment: Can you provide the markup as well?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the class?

Comment: @Apelavin Done :) oops you removed your comment, why?

Comment: please close this question or answer it yourself for it to be considered answered